# How to encode in lambda calculus

Tags: haskell, lambda, semantics, lambda-calculus

I am learning lambda calculus in Haskell and during that, i come across to this question.

[image]

And the solution of these question is this :

[image]

But I am unable to understand how they conclude the answer.
Like for eq, I don't understand how they come to this :  `λab.a b (b (λxy.y) (λxy.x))`
and same for nand. It will be really great if someone explains it and help me to understand this question.

Thank you.

Comment: Check out  the [Church boolean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding#Church_Booleans) Wikipedia article.

Comment: @Alec I checked it, but I don't understand how they are deriving those expression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm using the Haskell convention of writing λ as `\`.

From the comments it looks like you are having trouble with this part specifically:

```
eq = \a b. a b (b (\x y. y) (\x y. x))
```

So I'll just focus on this.

Our encoding of booleans is as functions which take two arguments.  `True` returns the first argument, `False` returns the second argument. The first paragraph gives the encoding directly:

```
True = \x y. x
False = \x y. y
```

We'll use the names instead of the lambda expressions until the very end.

We know that `eq` should take two arguments, the two booleans to be compared.  (The encoding of booleans itself takes two arguments, but this is different -- `eq` should take two arguments no matter how booleans are encoded)  So we know it should look like:

```
eq = \a b. _________________
```

At this point pretty much the only thing we can do is check one of the arguments to find out whether it's `True` or `False`.  `eq` is symmetrical so it doesn't really matter which one we ask about; let's pick `a` for no reason. The way we ask, according to the encoding, is to pass two arguments to the thing we want to find out about.

```
eq = \a b. a ____ ____
```

Where we haven't figured out what goes in the "holes" yet.  The first hole is what will be returned if `a` turns out to be `True`, the second one is what will be returned if it turns out to be `False`.

To figure out how to fill these holes, let's write the truth table for what we're trying to define:

```
a     |   b   |  eq a b
------+-------+---------
True  | True  |  True
True  | False |  False
False | True  |  False
False | False |  True
```

Notice that on the two rows where `a` is `True`, the `a == b` column is the exact same as the `b` column.  So when `a` is `True`, we just return `b`.  So we can fill in one of the holes:

```
eq = \a b. a b ____
```

Now notice in the table that when `a` is `False`, `a == b` is the opposite of the `b` column, so in that case we should invert `b` and return it.

To invert `b`, we want it to be `False` when `b` is `True` and vice versa.  In the encoding, that is:

```
b False True
```

And that's what we should return when `a` is `False`, so we fill in the other hole:

```
eq = \a b. a b (b False True)
```

Now we just unroll the definitions of `False` and `True`

```
eq = \a b. a b (b (\x y. y) (\x y. x))
```

And there you have it.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation. This makes sense to me now. I just have a problem to understand on how b False True is inverting b. I mean the case you gave is for when b is false. How it works for b when b is true.  Except this everything is clear now.

Comment: By our encoding, `b X Y` will be `X` when `b` is `True`, and `Y` when `b` is `False`.  So `b False True` means: `False` when `b` is `True`; `True` when `b` is `False`.

Comment: got it. Thank you. let me try this logic on nand now, and after that I am accepting it in case if i have no questions. Thank you very much...:)

Answer (score 7):

Let us first write the functions in question with actual data types (but no pattern-matching: only `if`/`then`/`else`):

```
data Bool = False | True -- recall this definition
not  a   = if a then False else True
eq   a b = if a then (if b then True  else False)
                else (if b then False else True )
nand a b = if a then (if b then False else True )
                else (if b then True  else True )
```

If you buy these definitions -- which are quite straightforward, just listing the truth tables of the functions -- then we can start doing some reasoning. First, we can simplify the outer branches of the `eq` and `nand` functions a little bit:

```
eq   a b = if a then b else not b
nand a b = if a then not b else True
```

And now we're basically done. We just replace every `False` and `True` with their `if`/`then`/`else` behavior, and replace every `if`/`then`/`else` with function application:

```
type Bool a = a -> a -> a
false a b = a -- `if False then a else b` becomes `false a b`
true  a b = b -- `if True  then a else b` becomes `true  a b`

not  a   = a false true   -- from `if a then False else True`
eq   a b = a b (not b)    -- from `if a then b else not b`
nand a b = a (not b) true -- from `if a then not b else True`
```

These are the definitions given in your solutions, though admittedly in Haskell syntax rather than lambda calculus syntax.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, but still the question is how they come up to this definition from the question.

Comment: I mean how they drive this part for eq : λab.a b (b (λxy.y) (λxy.x))

Comment: @WaqarAhmed Does it make sense how to get from the question to `eq a b = a b (not b)`? If so, I'll be happy to connect the dots from `eq a b = a b (not b)` to `eq = \a b -> a b (b (\x y -> y) (\x y -> x))`. In short: inline the definitions of `not`, `false`, and `true`, and move the arguments from one side of the equals sign to the other.

Comment: @WaqarAhmed Recall that in pure lambda calculus, `if x then y else z` is expressed as the simple application `x y z` -- this works because a boolean is encoded as a function taking two arguments and returning one of them (the first if true, the second if false).

Comment: @WaqarAhmed Or, if it doesn't make sense how to get from the question to `eq a b = a b (not b)`, then please let me know which of the three steps I outlined above for doing this is giving you trouble and I'll be happy to expand on that step.

Comment: @chi I understand how if works, but I am confuse how the first equation of eq derives.

Comment: @DanielWagner Thank you for your help. I actually understand the process how it comes from first equation to the last but I am confused in how the first equation derives from the lambda representation of True and False only. I mean do I need to memorize those equations? or is there a way to derive these equations, like in the first step of yours

Comment: @WaqarAhmed I am not sure I understood you. When you say "first equation" and "last equation", do you mean `eq = \ab. a b (b (\xy. y) (\xy. x))` and `eq = \ab. a b (not b)`, resp.? If so, then the answers to your question are: 1) of *course* you do not need to memorize those equations, and 2) those equations *are* the derivation -- it's just that they're listed in backwards order compared to how you invent them. That is, first you invent the last equation as in my answer; then you get the second-to-last equation by inlining `not`; then you get the first equation by inlining `false` and `true`.